# finding running applications on a system in a network

Tags: windows, networking

While on windows, suppose i connect to a wireless network that is within range.  Is it possible for the admin of this network to access my computer and find out the applications that are running on my system?  If so, how? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In a few roundabout ways, yes.

For one, they can monitor the sites you visit and the addresses you query. Some applications are very specific- World of Warcraft, for example, queries a specific set of addresses (it's servers), so from knowing the IP's you visit, some applications could be revealed.

Another possibility is that they could exploit any of your internet-enabled applications and insert their own code, but this is so minimally likely that it's not worth thinking about.

Finally, the admin can see the pages you visit, and could logically deduce the programs you have installed from your searching habits.

However, it all boils down to a simple condition- If your application uses the internet in any way, it can likely be deduced that you are using it. If your application is offline, or in offline mode, there is absolutely no way (aside from the tiny chance of an exploitable sharing capability in one of your applications).

Answer (score 0):

Yes he can, Every time you access a website or any application that goes to the world then it hits the router, if the router has capabilities of monitoring the traffic, then he can know what IP are you accessing and what ports are being used. therefore he can tell what you are the websites/application you are using, but he can't access your computer, only the router has a log of the activity.

Answer (score 0):

most people will check DHCP on the router to get your IP and then could, if you have left the ports / services open to do this, use a tool like "tasklist /S \192.168.2.100 or whatever your ip is, but most installs disable this kind of access by default, just double checking to make sure you are running some kind of protection between you and the router is good, although it wont stop them from seeing your unencrypted network transactions... i have logged onto many wireless routers that wern't mine and never had anything like that ever happen, even when i did open things up to see if they would.